# Upload files by GWT to Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gwt

I am working on an app that I need to upload files using GWT in the client side, then a servlet receives the uploaded file. My problem that I need to pass the file from the servlet to the ruby on rails controller (on the same server with the servlet). Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am do not see any particular problem here. Just prepare somewhere a non GWT html page with a form, an input and submit that can send a file to your Rails server. Now everything that you need is to prepare the same form using GWT components. In a case of standart GWT components you can use `FormPanel` and `FileUpload` components. Be sure that encoding and method was correctly set (example for built-in GWT components):

```
FormPanel form = prepareForm();
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

// sending file
form.submit();
```